# After creating the first list with choice fields I cannot lookup those fields - how do I keep data integrity and still link?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, list, lookup-column, choice-field

I have seen older answers that I can have a calculated field for the lookup but that seems silly and redundant.  I have 3 choice fields I would have to do that for for 100s of records.  Is that really my only option?  I would have thought this feature would be available?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to use the lookup column to link to a list with a few hundred records. For such situation, a common option is to use the JS link and make users be able to search for the record they want. Here are examples you can have a check:

https://ravisoftltd.wordpress.com/2014/05/05/convert-lookup-field-to-token-input-with-jslink/
https://prasadpathak.wordpress.com/2015/03/26/sharepoint-2013-getting-lookup-column-values-in-jslink/